# Return Map with value but get empty value

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to return a map with value but return me 0

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt');

function allTemp(){
const mapResultTemp = new Map();

const listTickets = require("../scripts/findTopic.js");

var options = {
    //***
};
var client = mqtt.connect('***', options);
client.on('connect', function () { // When connected
    // subscribe to a topic
    
    for (let [key, value] of listTickets.allTopics()) {
        const topicSelected = value;
        var newTopic = topicSelected.substring(1, topicSelected.length - 1);
        client.subscribe(newTopic, { qos: 0 });
        client.on("message", function (topic, message) {
            mapResultTemp.set(key, message.toString()); 
            console.log(mapResultTemp);
            // output: Map(1) { 0 => '24' }
            //         Map(2) { 0 => '24', 1 => '24' }
            //         Map(3) { 0 => '24', 1 => '24', 2 => '24' }
       
        });
        client.end();
    }
});
console.log(mapResultTemp);
// output: Map(0) {}
return mapResultTemp;
```

}

Actual result :

- Map(0) {}

Expected result :

- Map(3) { 0 => '24', 1 => '24', 2 => '24' }

Comment: At the time that you call `console.log(mapResultTemp);` (at the bottom of your code example), the callbacks you registered above have not yet run. It is not clear what your intent is here because you are returning `mapResultTemp` which will continue to be modified with every incoming message, even after this function completes. How do you intend to use this code?

Comment: I'm trying to use a library mqtt for get some values, so i want to return a map with a key and this specific value. What do you advise me to do? Because then, I want to call this function for get this in another file with another function

Comment: "get some values"? How many values? 3 exactly? An unknown number? What do you want to happen when a new message arrives? Does the consuming code need to be notified about every incoming message?

Comment: In my example this is 3 but it can be more. When the message arrives, need to push in the map with his index. And when all messages arrives, need to close client and return me all messages thanks to a map. Don't need to be notified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you add an event listener to the `"connect"` event, but before the callback is triggered (which is done after connecting), you are already checking the content of `mapResultTemp`. Same goes for the `"message"` events you are subscribing to. The event callbacks are async, you can't use them in a synchronous code flow. You will have to refactor your `allTemp` function code to handle an async flow of waiting for connect and message events:

```js
var mqtt = require('mqtt');

async function allTemp(){
const mapResultTemp = new Map();

const listTickets = require("../scripts/findTopic.js");

var options = {
    //***
};
var client = mqtt.connect('***', options);

// Wait for connection with a Promise
await new Promise(resolve => client.on('connect', resolve));

// subscribe to a topic
for (let [key, value] of listTickets.allTopics()) {
   const topicSelected = value;
   var newTopic = topicSelected.substring(1, topicSelected.length - 1);
   client.subscribe(newTopic, { qos: 0 });

   // Wait for message event
   const { topic, message } = await new Promise(resolve => client.once("message", (topic, message) => resolve({ topic, message }));

    mapResultTemp.set(key, message.toString()); 
    console.log(mapResultTemp);
    // output: Map(1) { 0 => '24' }
    //         Map(2) { 0 => '24', 1 => '24' }
    //         Map(3) { 0 => '24', 1 => '24', 2 => '24' }

   client.end();
}
console.log(mapResultTemp);
// output: Map(0) {}
return mapResultTemp;
```

Also note I changed your `.on("message", ...)` to `.once("message", ...)` because you'd add multiple event listeners in your loop and not removing them again, and I am assuming you are waiting for a single response per topic.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because both your `console.log(mapResultTemp);` and `return mapResultTemp;` are executed before you are connected to MQTT and/or receive any messages from subscribed topics. You might want to use a promise or async/await function to resolve all topics and messages before returning a Map object.

However, normally you would like to keep the connection and continue receiving messages. This way you could create a function that returns a value of your map when you call it.

Comment: Ok yeah it's better to keep the connection, I will try this